# Search for a value without knowing child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is a screenshot of my database

[Firebase Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP841.png)

I got the user key ID by writing the following code

```
userID=Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid();
```

I need to search for the child in that key **ROLE** to check if it's **STUDENT** or **INSTRUCTOR**

The problem is all the solutions I've found it online require a parent node to search through , I don't know if this user is a **student** or **instructor** , so I can't just write

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("students")
```

or

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("instructors")
```

I've tried to access the key directly but with no luck

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID);
```

So, how could this be implemented?

Comment: just search through both collections ?

Answer (score 0):

Check for both

```
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("students");
        dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("userID"));
                {
                    //isStudent = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

and

```
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("instructors");
        dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("userID"));
                {
                    //isInstructor = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

The value of `isStudent` and `isInstructor` will help you find, whether the user was a student or an instructor. If user id is present only in either student or instructor then only one of the variables `isStudent` or `isInstructor` will be `true`. If both are `false` then user does not exist.